# Using Automapper in .Net Core, how can I map the nested Foreign key relation?

Tags: .net, asp.net-core-mvc, entity-framework-core, automapper

I am trying to map the FK relation in my DTO class. However, I always get 'null' values as response in Postman.

Since the project includes companies that can be either clients/ partners etc. I have created a base table of company and created clients with FK relationship to company.

**Company Class**

```
public class Company
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string Street { get; set; }

    public int Zip { get; set; }

    [MaxLength(50)]
    public string City { get; set; }
```

**Client Class**

```
public class Client
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("CompanyId")]
    public Company Company { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }

    public ICollection<User> Users { get; set; }
        = new List<User>();

    public ICollection<Department> Departments { get; set; }
        = new List<Department>();
```

**ClientDTO**

```
public class ClientDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyStreet { get; set; }

    public ICollection<UserDto> Users { get; set; }
        = new List<UserDto>();
}
```

**AutoMapper in Startup Class**

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Client, ClientWithoutUsersDto>();
            cfg.CreateMap<Company, CompanyDto>();
            cfg.CreateMap<User, UserDto>();
        });
```

Whatever mapping I try I get the same **Json Response in Postmane**:

```
"id": 1,
"companyName": null,
"streetName": null
```

I am not sure whether Automapper supports nested FK mapping. I know that the User Collection works well.

Comment: How do you perform the mapping - with `Map` or with `ProjectTo`? If `Map`, are you loading the `Client.Company` property? It won't be populated by default, you need to `Include` it - see [Loading Related Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/querying/related-data)

Comment: Thanks Ivan, I am using Map for the mapping.  Where do I need to load the client.company? in the Client class ?

Comment: What is your query code for client data?

Comment: Try [ProjectTo](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Queryable-Extensions.html) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your query command whether it return the expected object `Company`.

Here is a mini-working demo for query.

```
var client = _context.Client.Include(c => c.Company).FirstOrDefault(c => c.Id == 1);
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>());
var result = Mapper.Map<ClientDto>(client);
```

Comment: The MapFroms are [not needed](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Flattening.html).